# Doctrine console missing: "dest-path"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

According to doctrine the generates entities command is as follow:

```
 orm:generate-entities [options] [--] <dest-path>
```

But I'm tried to execute the following command:

```
doctrine orm:generate-entities --update-entities /path/to/entities
```

I get the next error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
 Not enough arguments (missing: "dest-path").
```

I misunderstood the indications for usage of this command or there are another issue?

Comment: if you use this command inside a Symfony project then use the Symfony Console: bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle

Comment: I'm not inside Symfony project

Comment: Did you tried with `./path/to/entities`?

Comment: I tried, too, but the same error. I forget mention that I'm using XAMPP on Windows 10.

Comment: What exactly `/path/to/entities` contains in your case?

Comment: My entities classes generated first, now I want to update the getter and setter, after added new properties and relationship.

Comment: Did you typed exactly `/path/to/entities` in the command line? If not, what did you typed? (It's what I'm asking)

Comment: I tested with relative and absolute path.

Comment: You didn't answered my question... What *exactly* did you typed?

Comment: doctrine orm:generate-entities --update-entities /c/xampp/htdocs/CodeIgniter/application/models and doctrine orm:generate-entities --update-entities ./../../models

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error, however, I don't get an error, when I'm switching the order from

```
doctrine orm:generate-entities --update-entities /path/to/entities
```

to

```
doctrine orm:generate-entities ./path/to/entities/ --update-entities
```

maybe that's the problem, too?

Comment: That works with doctrine 2.6. Thanks. Somebody already reported that bug?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create entities from existing entites
Please run the following command:

```
- <i>php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:generate-entities -- .</i>
```

The data will be created in the root folder

And if you want to run update entities for the database, run the following command:

```
- <i>php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:schema-tool:update --force</i>
```

If it still does not work, please check with the command:

```
- <i>php vendor/bin/doctrine orm:info</i>
```

If they return an error, you need to modify the config as follows:

```
- <i>$config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(
    $paths, $isDevMode, null, null, false
);
- $config->setQueryCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache());
$entityManager = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);</i>
```

Then run what I said above again.
Good luck!